# Why boolean variable after While loop still true?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, wait, notify

I have a problem of understanding these methods, also the variable **empty**:

```java
    private String message;
    private boolean empty = true;

    public synchronized String read() {

        while (empty) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }

        empty = true; // i mean this line

        notifyAll();
        return message;
    }

    public synchronized void write(String message) {

        while (!empty) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }

        empty = false; // and this line

        this.message = message;
        notifyAll();
    }
```

Firstly i couldn't understand **wait()** and **notifyAll()** well, secondly why after the while loop in **read()**, empty is true, why not false?
the same with **write()** why not true after the while loop?

Sorry if my language is bad, i'm not native speaker.

Comment: Imagine if `empty` were renamed to `messageConsumed`.  Does that make it clearer?

Comment: @VGR not yet, why after while loop block, it still true in write()?

Comment: Because the `write` method must wait for the message to be read.  Once it has been read, the boolean field is set to false, to indicate that a new message is available for reading.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little oddly ordered - for example, I'd modify 'empty' after modifying 'message', seems more obvious to me - but...

This is a one-message buffer.

The 'write' method waits until 'empty' at which point it can set a message into 'message', making it not empty.

The 'read' method waits until 'not empty' at which point it can consume the message from 'message', making it empty again.

For my taste, the variable 'empty' is superfluous. I'd base it on the null/non-null state of 'message' (assuming that there's never a case for writing null as a message).

Answer (score 0):

`read` calls `wait` as long as `empty` is true: meaning there's nothing to read. Once `empty` is false, `read` sets `empty` to true (meaning it read whatever there is to be read), notifies any waiting threads, and returns.

`write` does the exact opposite.